# Using rails how to synchronize variable in controller to the view where the controller is the initiator of the update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I tried the long polling in AJAX, where the client calls the server requesting data at a certain interval. - The updating of list in UI was initiated by the client

Below are the code:

server_controller.rb

```
@@x=0
def results
  @@x++
  render :json =>  @@x
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<button id='get_value' class="btn">Run</button>
<ul id="value_variable_from_controller"><ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var getPoll=function getValue(trigger) { 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/server/results/',
      success: function(data, status) {
        if (data < 50){
            $('#value_variable_from_controller').append("<li>"+data+"</li>");
          setTimeout(getValue(true), 1000);}},})}
$(document).on("click","#get_value",getPoll);
```

The Question is how can i do it oppositely where the controller has the power to initiate/send the data and the list on HTML was synchronously updating/appending?

Answer (score 1):

This is more tricky to do, because you need an additional technology. HTTP and its [request-respond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response) model can't do this. A client (browser) can't receive requests from a server.

You'll end up with a bidirectional communication, because first the client ask the server things and later the server asks the client to update. A technology for doing this is [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Rails don't include this, so you need to add it via gems ([websockets-gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/websocket)) or/and probably an event driven, non-blocking server like node.js is useful as well.

There are different tutorials out there, which give you a start. [Here](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/02/27/adding-real-time-to-a-restful-rails-app/) is one example with two nice little graphics, which explain the situation.

Comment: thanks robin for the answer, how about not bidirectional, the controller will initiate the process to update the client without the client triggering the controller, was that possible? are there any simpler way to do that aside from using websockets?

Comment: You need something additional like websockets, because of the HTTPs request and response model. The server can not send a request to the client (browser) via HTTP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response

Comment: thanks robin for this reference.